# Understanding the proof of Theorem 10.1 in Montgomery & Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, theta-functions

In the last step of the proof of [Theorem 10.1](https://imgur.com/a/IRZHhmg) in the book *Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan* I couldn't understand what exactly "turn the path through an angle" means. I reparametrize $x$ to $xe^{-\frac12 \arg z}$ and I got $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x^2 e^{-\arg z}z} e^{-\frac12 \arg z} dx$$ which is not equal to the result that the authors claim, i.e. $$z^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x^2} dx = |z|^{-1/2} e^{-\frac12 \arg z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x^2} dx.$$

My question is how to show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x^2 z} dx = z^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x^2} dx$$ is true?

Comment: You forgot the $i$ in $e^{-i \frac{arg z} {2}}$. If one only does the rotation, then I guess the real things we know about the gaussian integral will take care of the scaling part, but why not do them both at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means (I think) to consider the following path:

[image: rotated contour]

That is, the rotated path is $\gamma(t) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{z}} = \frac{t}{ \sqrt{|z|}} e^{-i\frac{ arg z}{2}}$, so we also scale by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}$.

The vertical parts will tend to $0$ so we get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2z} dx
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{z}}\right)^2z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} dt
= z^{-\frac{1}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi t^2} dt.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)